# AuthBasicFake directive fails

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

Something simple like this:

```
   <Location /smcares/>
     AuthBasicFake demo demopass
   </Location>
```

throws an error:

```
Invalid command 'AuthBasicFake', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

auth_basic is loaded, apache version is 2.4.29

Comment: Why do you believe that mod_auth_basic is loaded? This error occurs when it is not.

Comment: A Fine question.   I was sure I checked, but sure enough apachectl -M showed it wasn't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the module is loaded

```
apachectl -M | grep auth_basic
```

You should get something like this:

```
auth_basic_module (shared)
```

If not, enable it and restart apache

```
sudo a2enmod auth_basic
```